How to Retrieve Deep Link Data in Flutter with Branch.io After App Install from store?
I'm working on integrating Branch.io for deep linking in a Flutter application and have encountered a specific use case that I need help with.
Scenario: My app uses Branch.io deep links containing specific parameters, including an openId link. The intended behavior is as follows:
